# Arch is installing files to a partition other than the defined by me

Tags: partitioning, installation, arch-linux

I am trying to install arch, and I partitioned a disk with only one partition of size 350G.
But when I try to download arch files it tells there is not enough disk space.
If i do df -h, I can see a /dev/sr0 with only 522M, 100% use, and mounted on /run/archiso/bootmnt.
How can I solve this problem.

Thanks in advance for all the help given

Comment: Are you sure you aren't trying to install onto the USB drive?

Comment: /dev/sr0 is used for CD and DVD drives. You're trying to install it on the wrong device.

Comment: What commands are you using to "download arch files"?

Answer (score 0):

`df -h` shows *mounted* devices. `/dev/sr0` is your installation media. You need to `fdisk -l` to determine what device you're looking for, since it won't already be mounted.

Comment: @user3710626 If my answer helped you, please upvote and accept.